# How do I download files from Google Drive to my server in parallel?

Tags: google-drive-api, backup

I want to download files from a Google Drive account to a server for backup purposes. The account holds about 40GB of files, which are mostly not owned by the user (so Google Takeout won't work).

I'd like to download the files in parallel to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Drive Linux client, which is conveniently called [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive). It's under development, but works pretty well.

It's got some dependencies (seemingly Go 1.2+), which can be hard to satisfy in a server environment. But it's possible to install.

```
$ drive init
$ drive pull
```

Will pull your whole Drive account down, but be fairly slow.

```
$ drive list | sed -e 's/^\///' | xargs -P 10 -I{} drive pull -quiet -no-prompt '{}'
```

Will download your top level folders in parallel, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to download in parallel, however you will reach quotas designed to prevent abuse of the system. In the developers console you can increase the rate limit so that a single user (you) can consume all the quota but you will eventually reach the rate limit exception with too many files downloaded in parallel. Basically google makes sure you dont go over a per-second limit given that its a free service or fixed price like google apps.

Comment: That's a good point. We only have 50GB in there, so it doesn't seem to have been an issue for us so far.